# How to trigger a service from one component to dismiss a popup in another component [angular]

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

For context, we've opted to use the angular router instead of the ionic navigation controller to handle routing.

I'm trying to handle navigation using the android back button. Pressing it when using an ionic framework emits global-level ion-back-button events. Since we're not using the ionic navigation controller, the only trigger to emit those events is pressing the android hardware back button. I've created a global listener for ion-back-button events, and inside of that listener I use a navigation service to handle page to page navigation. What that handler needs to do, which I'm having a hard time with, is it also needs to be able to check whether it's necessary to close popups before attempting page navigation.

I can't have higher priority back button listeners in the popup modals in the angular components because then the global back button listener would never fire.

This is what the handler in the app component looks like:

```
backButtonEvent() {
  this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
    if (!this.modalService.remove()) { // what should happen here is checking whether a popup exists. If the remove function returns no, then proceed to page navigation handling.
      const backUrl = this.backService.getBackURL();
      if (
        !backUrl.includes("dataload") /*previous page is not dataload*/ &&
        !backUrl.includes("login") /*previous page is not login */ &&
        !this.navCtrl.url.includes("dataload") /*current page is not dataload */ &&
        !this.navCtrl.url.includes("login") /*current page is not login */
      ) {
        this.navCtrl.navigateByUrl(backUrl);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And here is what most modals in the app look like:

```
  async showInformationModal() {
    const modalData: BasicModalData = {
      generic text: "text"
    };
    const infoModal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: BasicModalComponent,
      componentProps: {
        modalData
      },
      backdropDismiss: true,
      showBackdrop: true,
      cssClass: "modalClass"
    });
    return infoModal.present();
  }
```

What might make the most sense is creating a modal service with a function that can emit a "dismissed: true" property to assign to the infoModal. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is to use a GuardService and Routes "canDeactivate" attribute.

**navigation_guard_service.ts**:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationGuardService implements CanActivate, CanDeactivate<CUSTOM_OBJECT> {
    
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean|UrlTree { /*nothing here for now */ }
    
    canDeactivate(component: CUSTOM_OBJECT, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
        /*
        1. use "currentRoute" and/or "currentState" to recognize which is your current Page
        2. call your "Page.onDeactivate() : boolean" method you have previous created in that Page
        3. (here) return TRUE if you allow navigation to leave current URL, or FALSE to denied navigation (a 3rd possible return value is an "UrlTree" to change navigation to a different URL)
        */
    }
    
}
```

In Page's Module file:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(
    [
        { path: '', children: [
            { path: ROUTE_LOGIN, loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.ChooserPageModule)/*, canActivate: [NavigationGuardService]*/, canDeactivate: [NavigationGuardService] },
            { path: '', redirectTo: ROUTE_LOGIN, pathMatch: 'full' },
        ]},
        { path: '', redirectTo: ROUTE_AUTH_LOGIN, pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: ROUTE_AUTH_LOGIN }
    ]
)],
exports: [RouterModule],
})
```